# Stripe payment gateway implementation

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I want to validate the stripe payment gateway token id before charging customer using that token id.

Can we do this in stripe payment gateway?

Development language could be any for validating token id

Comment: check the api documents

Comment: Thanks for suggestions but I already check them . If you have any idea about this please tell me

Comment: we are not here to support every api\payment gateway\ third party supplier on the planet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one way to validate `token`, that is to retrieve `token` details

Check here https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_token

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_*******lfQ2");

\Stripe\Token::retrieve("tok_******gxZwU");
```

It will throws an error if invalid `token_id` is passed

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Does it also make token void . As per I know token can used once after generated.@meera

Comment: no it will not make your token void as you are not using token for any charge or customer activity.it will just check whether token is valid or not!

Comment: can you please accept the Answer if it worked for you?

Comment: Fine Working This code: [Go this Page](https://www.phpcodingstuff.com/blog/how-to-integrate-stripe-payment-gateway-in-laravel-8.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to validate a card token. Tokens are short-time lived and should be used right after it's created.

You have to *use* the token to ensure that the card is valid. When you create a customer via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) and pass the token as `source: "tok_XXXX"`, Stripe will run a $0/$1 authorization on the card with the bank to make sure it's valid. Otherwise you call the Create Charge [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) to try and charge the card and the bank either accepts the charge or they decline it.